# start: Unknown job: monit

Tags: ubuntu, services, monit

So what is causing this error in the following case?

1. /etc/init.d/monit exists
2. installed using `sudo apt-get install monit`

standard install via apt

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo apt-get install monit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
monit is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chef-zero erubis ohai ruby-diff-lcs ruby-erubis ruby-hashie ruby-highline
  ruby-ipaddress ruby-mime-types ruby-mixlib-authentication ruby-mixlib-cli
  ruby-mixlib-config ruby-mixlib-log ruby-mixlib-shellout ruby-net-ssh
  ruby-net-ssh-gateway ruby-net-ssh-multi ruby-rack ruby-rest-client
  ruby-sigar ruby-systemu ruby-yajl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

`/etc/init.d/monit` exists

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cat /etc/init.d/monit
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          monit
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs
# Should-Start:      $all
# Should-Stop:       $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: service and resource monitoring daemon
# Description:       monit is a utility for managing and monitoring
#                    processes, programs, files, directories and filesystems
#                    on a Unix system. Monit conducts automatic maintenance
#                    and repair and can execute meaningful causal actions
#                    in error situations.
### END INIT INFO

set -e

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

DAEMON=/usr/bin/monit
CONFIG=/etc/monit/monitrc
NAME=monit
DESC="daemon monitor"
MONIT_OPTS=
PID="/run/$NAME.pid"

# Check if DAEMON binary exist
[ -f $DAEMON ] || exit 0

[ -f "/etc/default/$NAME" ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

MONIT_OPTS="-c $CONFIG $MONIT_OPTS"

monit_not_configured () {
  if [ "$1" != "stop" ]
  then
    printf "\tplease configure $NAME and then edit /etc/default/$NAME\n"
    printf "\tand set the \"START\" variable to \"yes\" in order to allow\n"
    printf "\t$NAME to start\n"
  fi
  exit 0
}

monit_checks () {
  # Check if START variable is set to "yes", if not we exit.
  if [ "$START" != "yes" ]
  then
    monit_not_configured $1
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    monit_checks $1
    if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON -- $MONIT_OPTS 1>/dev/null
    then
      log_end_msg 0
    else
      log_end_msg 1
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    if start-stop-daemon --retry TERM/5/KILL/5 --oknodo --stop --quiet --pidfile $PID 1>/dev/null
    then
      log_end_msg 0
    else
      log_end_msg 1
    fi
    ;;
  reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC configuration" "$NAME"
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal HUP --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON -- $MONIT_OPTS 1>/dev/null
    then
      log_end_msg 0
    else
      log_end_msg 1
    fi
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    start-stop-daemon --retry TERM/5/KILL/5 --oknodo --stop --quiet --pidfile $PID 1>/dev/null
    if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON -- $MONIT_OPTS 1>/dev/null
    then
      log_end_msg 0
    else
      log_end_msg 1
    fi
    ;;
  syntax)
    $DAEMON $MONIT_OPTS -t
    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc -p $PID $DAEMON $NAME
    ;;
  *)
    log_action_msg "Usage: /etc/init.d/$NAME {start|stop|reload|restart|force-reload|syntax|status}"
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

there is no monit service running

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ps aux | grep monit
vagrant   7338  0.0  0.0  10460   936 pts/0    S+   22:55   0:00 grep --color=auto monit
```

attempt to start monit service, fails

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo service monit start
start: Unknown job: monit

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ps aux | grep monit
vagrant   7675  0.0  0.0  10460   932 pts/0    S+   22:56   0:00 grep --color=auto monit
```

Update: **3-Sep-2016**

I am using vagrant to create a virtual machine running ubuntu/trusty 14.04.

`/etc/init.d/monit start` seems to work

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/monit start
 * Starting daemon monitor monit                                                                                                            /etc/monit/conf.d/postfix.conf:11: Warning: hostname did not resolve 'INSERT_THE_RELAY_HOST'
                                                                                                                                     [ OK ]
```

update: 2016-09-04

The service name is actually `mmonit`, not `monit`. :)

`sudo service mmonit start` works

Comment: Does directly executing `/etc/init.d/monit start` work? Also which Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: Is this a container? So the guest is running Ubuntu 14.04; what Linux distro is running on the host?

Comment: @heemayl `/etc/init.d/monit start` does seem to work

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, it is vagrant creating a virtualbox machine with ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service name is actually `mmonit`, not `monit`. :)

`sudo service mmonit start` works

Comment: I did exactly that, but then people looking for answer may get confused and go away. To just quickly see the solution, I browse for a green tick mark. Many users may be doing that too.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was going through the Low Quality Posts review queue too quickly and hadn't realised that was the actual solution to your problem (lots of users mistakenly add extra question details by posting them as an answer). Your answer was wholly appropriate so have an upvote.